# Number of shortest paths

Tags: combinatorics

In a city M roads run East West and N roads run North South. Suppose they are parallel and they are equidistant. Find number of shortest paths from one corner to diagonally opposite corner.

What I did was to formulate this alegbraically say the units moved in ith row is r(i) and in jth coloumn is c(j) then sum of r's is m and C's is n. Then using the formula for number of solutions I get solutions of individual coloumn and row equations. But  I later realized that two equations are not independent. If r1 =1 then c1 becomes 0. Now I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reach the diagonally opposite corner, you need to take $M - 1$ horizontal steps and $N - 1$ vertical steps, for a total of $M + N - 2$ steps. To calculate the number of paths, it simply comes down to deciding when to move horizontally and when to move vertically. Since there are $M - 1$ horizontal steps and $N - 1$ vertical steps, the number of shortest paths equals:

$${M + N - 2 \choose M - 1} = {M + N - 2 \choose N - 1} = \frac{(M + N - 2)!}{(M - 1)! (N - 1)!}$$

Comment: Correct. I agree with this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fun problem in recursion. First note that the shortest paths from one corner of a grid to another corner of the grid are made up of only north moves and east moves (I am making a choice of starting at (0,0) and ending at (n,n)). Let $N(i,j)$ be the number of shortest paths to the lattice point $(i,j)$. Then, $$N(i,j) = N(i-1,j)+N(i,j-1)$$ since to get to this point one must come from the west or come from the south. This is the famous recursion that creates pascals triangle. The south east diagonals will contain the binomial coefficients. Therefore, the number of shortest paths form $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ is the central binomial coefficient $${2n \choose n} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about how to solve the recurrence relation. Additionally you have to reach m,n not n,n. One more thing is I couldn't understand how did the binomial coefficient come up.